# Disabling WARNING LOGS in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

When i am starting tomcat i am getting so many of WARNING MESSAGES like

```
File not found: DerbyLocale.jar
```

is missing like that, but i do not require those jars for my application.

How can i disable those WARNING messages, can anyone suggest?

Comment: for your information i am using TOMCAT v8.0.50

Comment: I'm confused by the collection of tags you started with. What OS is tomcat running in? Why the "eclipse " tag?

Comment: There are several ways of suppressing those messages, however I would suggest finding out how to install the Derby jar dependencies.  Or uninstalling it if not needed.